# How can I import the full location from the game into Blender?

Tags: unity-game-engine, import, location, blender, scene

How can I import the full location from the game (made on Unity) into Blender? The screenshot shows a set of folders that were in the location file in the game itself.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLfbg.png)

I can easily assemble a location from Mesh files, but at the texturing stage I don't know what to do. Manually is too much work. How do I import the entire location from these folders so that the textures are also applied?

Comment: Please review *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)* and *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74811584/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can import your unity file to blender only if you have unity file in FBX form , save unity or export unity file in FBX file and then go in blender , You will get an option to "IMPORT IN FBX FORMAT" , click and import the unity file in that.

Answer (score -1):

Whether textures are auto-applied has to do with whether whoever made the models embedded the textures into the models when exporting them. For this, whoever made the model needs to export the model in FBX format and make sure in export settings that the textures are embedded inside the FBX file.

Also, why are you working with Unity at the texturing stage? Lookdev should be done in a 3d program (substance painter etc). Use neutral lighting for best results (white skydome light).